# powershell script get disk info (ssd, hdd) remote computer by list

Tags: powershell

I have tried to build a script to get disk info, like the title of this question.

Below is the script, but when its executed nothing is written in the txt out.
I use the same script for other queries and it work.

```
$computerlist = get-content -path c:\temp\listapc\pclist.txt
$output = @()
$computer = 0

ForEach ($computer in $computerlist)
    {
        if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -Quiet)
        {
            Write-Host "$Computer OK."
            $singleOutput =  Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername $Computer -Filter "DriveType=3" | Select drivetype
            $output+= $singleOutput
        } else {
            Write-Host "$Computer is offline. Skipping..."
        }
    }
    $output | Out-File -filepath c:\temp\resultdiskinfo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your script in my environment and it worked. I've got the drivetypes written in the txt file. It didn't work though when my computer names were wrong for example. Then the test-connection failed and the $output was empty.

Please check with

```
[bool]$output
```

That this variable is $true and not $false.
If $false, your variable is empty and therefore you'll receive no output.
For debugging reasons you could also remove the "-quiet" parameter to make sure that the ping works well.

Comment: Thank You for your answer, I added "[bool]$output" in the script and when I try to run it, return "False".

Comment: That means your $output variable is empty. That is the reason why nothing is written into your txt file. There must be a problem anywhere else in the script. Please remove the "quiet" paramater to check if an error occurs when executing the "Test-Connection" cmd.

Comment: I rewrite now the script and it work :) IDK...

Comment: Thank you a lot for your support. I have anoter ask for you.. 
I realized now that the "win32_logicaldisk" command returns the drive type of the computer (local disk, network, etc...) but I want to know what the medya type disk is (ssd, hdd, etc...). Do you know what the substitute command is?

Comment: This might be help you:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-powershell-to-identify-ssd/

Answer (score 0):

I post here the right final script which can help other users

```
$computerlist = get-content -path c:\temp\listapc\elenco.txt
$output = @()
$computer = 0
$pingno = 0

ForEach ($computer in $computerlist)
    {
        if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -Quiet)
        {
            $singleOutput =  Get-WmiObject -Class MSFT_PhysicalDisk -Computername $Computer -Namespace root\Microsoft\Windows\Storage | Select __SERVER, " || ", 
                @{
                    name="MediaType"; 
                    expression=
                    {
                        switch ($_.MediaType)
                        { 
                            3 {"HDD"}
                            4 {"SSD"} 
                        } 
                    }
                }
            
            $output+= $singleOutput,
                "================================
                
                "
            
            [bool]$output #That this variable is $true and not $false. If $false, your variable is empty and therefore you'll receive no output. For debugging reasons you could also remove the "-quiet" parameter to make sure that the ping works well.
        
        } else {
            
            $output+= "$Computer is offline.",
                "================================
                
                "
        }
    }
    $output | Out-File -filepath c:\temp\resultdiskinfo.txt
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).